# DBEdits puxando valores da linha selecionada do DBGrid mesmo no modo INSERT!

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Venho por meio deste retirar uma dúvida sobre o DBEdit, tenho um formX que contém uma DBGrid relacionada à tabela de pagamentos e no mesmo form tenho um botão para receber pagamentos, quando apertado esse botão abre um novo formY com alguns campos para inserir os dados do novo pagamento a ser recebido (Ao ser mostrado o formY ele já altera a tabela relacionada ao DBGrid para o modo [insert])! Porém, quando deixo alguma linha da DBGrid selecionada anteriormente ao clique do botão, esses campos do formY que abrem estão puxando os valores da linha selecionada da DBGrid do formX, alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Verifique se a opção dgCancelOnExit do DBGrid está igual a True, desconfio que o DataSet está saindo de Insert porque essa opção está habilitada e o DBGrid está perdendo o foco

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de inserir registros em uma tela separada é chamar o método  `Append` do `DataSet` antes de abrir a tela. Há várias formas de fazer isso, uma simples seria essa:

Ex:

```
var
  frmY: TfrmY;
begin
  //uma forma boa de trabalhar é passar o dm
  //no construtor, ou ter um método separado
  //para passar o dm para o form
  frmY := TFormY.Create(nil, dm);
  try

    dm.AdicionarRegistroY;

    //a validação dos dados você pode 
    //chamar no "Ok" do frmY, e apenas
    //chamar ModalResult = mrOk quando
    //passar pela validação
    frmY.ShowModal = mrOk then
      dm.GravarRegistroY; 

  finally FreeAndNil(frmY) end;  
...
```

No datamodule:

```
procedure Tdm.AdicionarRegistroY;
begin
  if (cdsY.State in [dsEditModes]) then
    cdsY.Cancel;
  cdsY.Append;
end;

procedure Tdm.GravarRegistroY;
begin
  if (cdsY.State in [dsEditModes]) then
    cdsY.Post;

  //caso use TClientDataSet, lembrar também de
  //tratar o ReconcileError
  if cdsY.ChangeCount > 0 then
    cdsY.ApplyUpdates; 
end;
```

Esse código repetitivo pode ser colocado em uma classe, ou em um ancestral comum dos seus datamodule de cadastro, ou componentizado de alguma forma.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).